# Transpose 1 dimensional array in python?

Tags: python, transpose

I have an array correctClassifierLabels with [ 1.  1. -1. -1.] and I need to turn it into [[ 1.] [ 1.][ 1.][ 1.]] I have tried

```
correctClassifierLabels = correctClassifierLabels[:,0:1]
```

and

```
zip(*correctClassifierLabels)
```

and

```
transpose(correctClassifierLabels)
```

and none of them worked for me

Comment: It is hard to tell from your example (some negatives disappear) but I think you're just looking for `correctClassifierLabels[:, np.newaxis]`, inserting another axis.

Comment: what is np supposed to represent here? I am getting that I am supposed to define it

Comment: NumPy, the Python library. Are you following some IPython notebook using Scikit, or are you doing this yourself with pure Python?

Comment: just pure python